# find tekst in files in subfolders

Tags: linux, find

So this question might have been asked before, but after some hours of searching (or searching wrongfully) I decided to ask this question. 
If it's already been answered before, please link me the question and close this one.

here's my issue.

I have a folder on my filesystem, ie "files". this folder has got a lot of subfolders, with their subfolders. some levels deep, they all have a file which is called the same in all folders. In that file, a lot of text is in it, but it's not ALL the same. I need to have a list of files that contains a certain string.

I KNOW I can do this with

```
find ./ -type f -exec grep -H 'text-to-find-here' {} \;
```

but the main problem is: it will get over every single file on that filesystem. as the filesystem contains MILLIONS of files, this would take up a LONG time, specially when I know the exact file this piece of text should be in.

visually it looks like this:

```
foobar/foo/bar/file.txt 
foobar/foobar/bar/file.txt
foobar/barfoo/bar/file.txt
foobar/raboof/bar/file.txt
foobar/oof/bar/file.txt
```

I need a specific string out of file.txt (if that string exists..) 
(and yes: the file in /bar/ is ALLWAYS called file.txt...)

Can anyone help me on how to do so? i'm breaking my head on an "easy" solution :o

Thnx,
Daniel

Comment: so all those files have the same name `file.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-name` option to filter by name:

```
find . -type f -name file.txt -exec grep -H 'text-to-find-here' {} +
```

And if it's always in a directory named `bar`, you can use `-path` with a wildcard:

```
find . -type f -path '*/bar/file.txt' -exec grep -H 'text-to-find-here' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

With single GNU ***grep*** command:

```
grep -rl 'pattern' --include=*file.txt
```

---

> **`--include=glob`**
>
> Search only files whose name matches glob, using wildcard